MariaDB Запрос по нескольким значениям
Есть такой запрос в котором есть переменная $Host в которую из графаны идут значения.
SELECT clock * 1000 as time, value AS "Пинг $Host" 
FROM history_uint 
WHERE itemid = (
    SELECT i.itemid
    FROM items i
    JOIN hosts h ON i.hostid = h.hostid
    WHERE i.name = 'ICMP: ICMP ping' AND h.host LIKE CONCAT('%', (SELECT(REGEXP_SUBSTR($Camera, '\\d+-\\d+.*'))), '%')
)
AND clock >= ROUND(${__from}/1000)
AND clock <= ROUND(${__to}/1000)

Если приходит одно значение то все хорошо. Если их несколько то все ломается. Нужно сделать так чтоб при нескольких значениях возвращалось несколько результатов по этим значениям, как это можно реализовать?

Приходит одно значение где? Ломается как? при нескольких значениях возвращалось несколько результатов - значения чего, результатов каких?

Как именно выглядит передаваемое в запрос значение (ещё лучше - запрос с подставленным переданным значением), если хост один и если их несколько? Для каждого - покажите также требуемый результат.

Вангую - внутренний запрос возвращает больше одного значения и все падает из-за =. Скорее всего достаточно будет заменить на in
